# Counting the number of occurrences of each element in Matlab

Tags: matlab, maps

What is the most efficient way that can be implemented in MATLAB in order to find the number of occurrences of each element in a vector?

For example:

```
A = { 'AA AB AC CD'; 'BA AC CF GD'; 'AA AB AC CD'; 'CF GD TH EF'; 'AA AB AC CD'}
```

I want to get that "AA AB AC CD" was repeated 3 times, "BA AC CF GD" was repeated once, and "CF GD TH EF " was repeated once.

I don't actually care if the output of the function was 2 vectors, one for the strings and the other for the count, or any other output that would do the job.

My approach was to take each string and count the number of occurrences and remove all the occurrences from the initial vector, so that the worst case running time would be in the order of n^2 where n is the number of elements in A.

But I need a more efficient approach. Using C++ for example, I can use maps in order to make the running time almost linear, but sadly, Maps are not implemented in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming `A` to be a cell array -

```
A = { 'AA AB AC CD'; 'BA AC CF GD'; 'AA AB AC CD'; 'CF GD TH EF'; 'AA AB AC CD'}
```

For solving the stated problem, few approaches can be suggested here.

**Approach #1**

This is a straight-forward-no-messing-around approach -

```
[unique_strings,~,labels] = unique(A,'stable');
counts = histc(labels,1:max(labels))
```

**Approach #2**

This is a performance oriented solution that works with converting the cell array to a `2D` array -

```
[~,idx,labels] = unique(double(char(A)),'rows','stable')
counts = histc(labels,1:max(labels))
unique_strings = A(idx)
```

**Approach #3**

This is another performance oriented solution that works with converting the cell array to a `1D` array after merging all characters in a cell into a single number -

```
num_array = char(A)-0
pow10_vals = 10.^(size(num_array,2)-1:-1:0)
[~,idx,labels] = unique(num_array*pow10_vals','stable') %//'
counts = histc(labels,1:max(labels))
unique_strings = A(idx)
```

---

Output you would get -

```
>> unique_strings
unique_strings = 
    'AA AB AC CD'
    'BA AC CF GD'
    'CF GD TH EF'
>> counts
counts =
     3
     1
     1
```

The output can be shown in a fancy way as well with `table` -

```
>> table(unique_strings,counts)
ans = 
    unique_strings    counts
    ______________    ______
    'AA AB AC CD'     3     
    'BA AC CF GD'     1     
    'CF GD TH EF'     1
```

Please note that if you don't care about the order of strings, you can skip `'stable'` option with the above mentioned approaches and that might be a tiny bit more efficient.

Comment: If you don't care about the order of strings, you can skip `'stable'` option and that might be a tiny bit more efficient.

Comment: This definitely works, Thx! However any idea about the complexity of this function? Any idea how can i take a look at its code?

Comment: @husseinhammoud By `look at code`, you mean some explanation I am guessing. So, it's fairly simple - First step with `unique` gets us the unique strings and assigns each cell a label based on their common-ness with other cells. In the next step, we use those labels and get a count for each label that corresponds to each unique string/cell found in the previous step. Does that explain it somewhat?

Comment: By look at code I meant in order to study its running time, Because my work will be on huge amount of data and efficiency really counts.. However since this is a MATLAB built-in function it is supposed to be efficient :) I'll try it out.. Thx alot

Comment: @husseinhammoud Added another performance oriented solution for you to test out! Also let me ask you, do you care about the order of strings in the output?

Comment: Yeah i do care about it, that's why i find 'stable' useful here :)

Comment: @husseinhammoud Awesome! So you have three approaches to test out now! :)

Comment: @husseinhammoud If you are to be absolutely correct about results, please make this edit for `Approach #3` - `pow10_vals = 100.^(size(num_array,2)-1:-1:0)` and rest of the code stays the same.

Comment: Can you please explain ur code in the 3rd approach?

Comment: @husseinhammoud Oh it basically converts the cell array into a char array with `char` and then we convert that to a 2D double array with `-0` and then we merge all the numbers in a row of that double array to a single number by assigning each of them digits place as in a number. Thus, we are left with a 1D array, which is then processed through `unique` and rest is the same as the other approaches.